# Sort multiple columns of data to match an index

Tags: excel, sorting, match

I am trying to match a report that is updated continually to an index that has been presorted based on building function. The report randomly orders the new entries, and I am simply trying to automatically sort the new reports so they match the order of the pre-made index. At the same time I want to keep all the columns to the right of the report attached to its respective building. The screenshot shows what I am trying to do, I just want the highlighted report re-sorted so that it matches the index, with all the data matched to its building.

[image]

Comment: Your image does not work, can you provide a concrete example?

Comment: What should the results look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding another column in your data....Add the following in column B

`=MATCH(C2,$A:$A,0)`

This will return the row number of the match in column A. Then you can sort on column B, and your entries will be in order.